# How to center a fixed table at the top

Tags: html, css

I'm doing a school project and what I want is a way to navigate the page as seen here:

```css
body
{
background-color:rgb(255, 255, 240);
}
a
{
font-family:Pin;
font-size:50;
text-decoration: none;
color:black;
}
table
{
width:500px;
text-align:center;
width:500px; 
}
```

```html
<table align="center">
<tr>
<td><a href="">Hem</a></td>
<td><a href="">Om</a></td>
<td><a href="">Kontakt</a></td>
<td><a href="">Oss</a></td>
</tr>
</table>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
```

But when I scroll down I want it to be fixed to the top of the page. I've tried using position:fixed, but then it's to the left and then I'm not sure how to center it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `fixed` position and adjust as below:

```
table {
    width:500px;
    text-align:center;
    position:fixed;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-250px; /*1/2 of the total width*/
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tjqzfrb0/

Answer (score 1):

```
table {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
}
```

Comment: Then the text goes to the left and I've got a new problem.